# How to write the Test class for a Schedulable class which uses a custom label ( converted to date in the apex class)

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, scheduled-apex, customlabel

This is my code ( apex class) below

```
global class deleteclass implements Schedulable{
   
  global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      Datetime dt = DateTime.valueOf(System.Label.OldRecords);
        List<ErrorLog__c> ErrorLog = [select Id FROM ErrorLog__c WHERE createddate < :dt];
        if(!ErrorLog.isEmpty())
            delete ErrorLog;
      Database.emptyRecycleBin(ErrorLog);
    }
 }
```

Note : `OldRecords` is the custom label which contains value `= Last_n_days:60` ( fetches the records of last 2 months and more).
How to write this a Test class for this.

Answer (score 1):

Apex allows you to set the `CreateDate` [field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_test.htm), all you need is to use below during data creation,

```
 Test.setCreatedDate(<recordId>, datetimevalue);
```

In your case, when you are creating the Error log use below,

```
ErrorLog__c err = new ErrorLog__c();
..
insert err;
Test.setCreatedDate(err.Id, DateTime.newInstance(2020,12,12));
```

This will ensure that create record is 6 months old and is picked up in the test execution